# Как в JavaScript вывести дни месяца на неделю вперед?

Tags: javascript, дата

Ребят, делаю приложение прогноза погоды, и мне нужно показать погоду на неделю вперед, соответсвенно у каждой колонки с данными о погоде должна быть своя дата, к примеру начиная от сегодня и заканчивая днем через 6 дней. Естественно дни должны обновляться каждый день, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `date.getTime()` возвращает количество миллисекунд, прошедших с 1-го января 1970. А конструктор `Date` умеет создавать новый объект из полученного числа (миллисекунд). Можно в цикле добавлять мсек для каждого дня:

```js
const DAY_MILSEC = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

let today = new Date().getTime();
for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  let date = new Date(today + DAY_MILSEC * i);

  console.log(getDay(date));
}

function getDay(date) {
  let days = ["Вскр", "Пон", "Втр", "Сред", "Чтв", "Пят", "Суб"];
  return date.getDate() + " " + days[date.getDay()];
}
```

Формально, массив нужно вынести из функции, чтобы не создавать его 7 раз подряд при вызове. Но здесь это не имеет особого значения)

Comment: Вот только не могу понять, каким образом использовать это на странице?)

Comment: @БогданЧубко О_О Не знаю, если у вас там 7 карточек с каким-нибудь классом class="card-day", можно перед циклом записать `let card = document.querySelectorAll(".card-day");` а внутри цикла, вместо console.log - `card[i].textContent = getDay(date);`

Comment: Да я вообще на React пишу, но я вас примерно понял, сейчас что-то придумаю)